# Custom word translator in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Update: scroll to see my solution, can it be improved?**

So I have this issue, I am building a word translator thats translates english to 'doggo', I have built this in vanilla JS but would like to do it React.

My object comes from firebase like this

```
dictionary = [
    0: {
        name: "paws",
        paws: ["stumps", "toes beans"] 
    }
    1: {
        name: "fur",
        fur: ["floof"] 
    }
    2: {
        name: "what"
        what: ["wut"]
    }
]
```

I then convert it to this format for easier access:

```
dictionary = {
    what : ["wut"],
    paws : ["stumps", "toe beans"],
    fur : ["floof"]
}
```

Then, I have two text-area inputs one of which takes input and I would like the other one to output the corresponding translation. Currently I am just logging it to the console.

This works fine to output the array of the corresponding word, next I have another variable which I call 'levelOfDerp' which is basically a number between 0 - 2 (set to 0 by default) which I can throw on the end of the console.log() as follows to correspond to the word within the array that gets output.

```
dictionary.map(item => {
  console.log(item[evt.target.value][levelOfDerp]);
});
```

When I do this I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". I am trying to figure out how to get past this error and perform the translation in real-time as the user types.

Here is the code from the vanilla js which performs the translation on a click event and everything at once. Not what I am trying to achieve here but I added it for clarity.

```
function convertText(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let text = inputForm.value.toLowerCase().trim();
    let array = text.split(/,?\s+/);
    array.forEach(word => {
      if (dictionary[word] === undefined) {
        outputForm.innerHTML += `${word} `;
        noTranslationArr.push(word);
      } else {
        let output = dictionary[word][levelOfDerp];
        if (output === undefined) {
          output = dictionary[word][1];
          if (output === undefined) {
            output = dictionary[word][0];
          }
        }
        outputForm.innerHTML += `${output} `;
        hashtagArr.push(output);
      }
    });
    addData(noTranslationArr);
  }
```

Also here is a link to the translator in vanilla js to get a better idea of the project https://darrencarlin.github.io/DoggoSpk/

**Solution, but could be better..**

I found a solution but I just feel this code is going against the reason to use react in the first place.. My main concern is that I am declaring variables to store strings inside of an array within the function (on every keystroke) which I haven't really done in React, I feel this is going against best practice?

```
  translate = evt => {

    // Converting the firebase object 
    const dict = this.state.dictionary;
    let dictCopy = Object.assign(
      {},
      ...dict.map(item => ({ [item["name"]]: item }))
    );

    let text = evt.target.value.toLowerCase().trim();
    let textArr = text.split(/,?\s+/);
    let translation = "";

    textArr.forEach(word => {
      if (dictCopy[word] === undefined) {
        translation += `${word} `;
      } else {
        translation += dictCopy[word][word][this.state.derpLvl];
      }
    });
    this.setState({ translation });
  };
```

Comment: just move dict conversion to `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1):

`levelOfDerp` is not defined, try to use 'levelOfDerp' as string with quotes.

```
   let output = dictionary[word]['levelOfDerp' ];
```

Comment: Hi, thats not it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because `setState()` is asynchronous, so by the time it's executed your `evt.target.value` reference might not be there anymore. The solution is, as you stated, to store that reference into a variable.

Maybe consider writing another function that handles the object conversion and store it in a variable, because as is, you're doing the conversion everytime the user inputs something.